# Is there a way or add-0n to show an image or file is linked from an entry if a user tries to delete it?

Tags: assets, files

A client wants to prevent an editor from renaming or deleting an asset/file/entry that is linked from anywhere on the site.  I cannot find an add-on that does this.  They are requesting a list that shows links to the item they want to rename/delete with an options of actions to take.